# How do I read data from a single document in flutter firebase base once (not in real time)?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering how I can read from a firebase database once. I want to be able to read from a document that has the same ID as the user that's logged in, via the firebase authentication, and then return the string of the user's name.
Right now I am getting 3 errors on line 12 under the get method

1. Function expressions can't be named
2. Expected an identifier
3. The getter '(' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentRefence<Object?>'

```
class DatabaseService {
  final CollectionReference usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

  final String uid;

  DatabaseService(this.uid); 

  Future<String> getUserName() async {
    String name = '';

    var document = await usersCollection.doc(uid);
    document.get() => then((doc) {
      name = doc('name');
    });

    return name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`async/await` should use of api calls not on the database path reference.

Just make sure of the `snapshap.data()` is correct, otherwise you can use my code as a reference.

```
Future<String> getUserName() async {
    var document = usersCollection.doc(uid);
    var snapshot = await document.get();
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();
    name = data['name'];
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just wondering though for ref.get() did you mean document.get() because ref is not initialized anywhere else?

Comment: @WilliamDoyle i didn't notice about that, Just put `document.get()` instead of `ref.get()`